# can we assign object array index value to any integer type variable in java?

Tags: java

```
void bubbleSort(Customer[] c) {
    int temp = 0;
    temp = c[0]; // problem here
}
```

Comment: Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `c[0]` is of type `Customer` while `temp` is of type `int`. You cannot assign a reference of one type to a different one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because `temp` is integer type, while `c[0]` is Customer type

Comment: ok is there any other approach in java because i want to sort object values!!

Comment: Do you want to sort the array of castomers? @tech kenn

Comment: yes array of customers according to their salary

Comment: @Techkeen Then why not make `temp` to be of type `Customer` and do the comparison.

Comment: `Arrays.sort` allows sorting an array of any type by providing a custom comparator as second argument.

Comment: but i want to sort the values using some sorting algorithms such as bubble sort.

Comment: You need in Castumer class a method named `getSalary` that returns the salary of type int, than you can write `int temp=c[0].getSalary` @Techkeen

Comment: yes i used it but task is to sort values using some algorithm

Comment: You can put all the salarys in new array of type int, and after you can sort this array with sort algorithms @Techkeen

Comment: ok i try to code again with that method

Comment: if (c[i] < c[i+1])// error occur 
                {
                     int temp = c[0].getSalary();
                     c[0] = c[1];
                     c[1].getSalary()= temp; // error occur in that line now 
        
                }

Comment: Try `if(c[i].getSalary()<c[i+1].getSalary())`

Comment: ok that resolve and for second error

Comment: c[1].getSalary()= temp;

Comment: unexpected type error

Comment: That's because `c[1].getSalary` isn't a variable, if u want to change `c[1]'s` salary you need a methode `setSalary`

Comment: package customer;


public class Customer
{
    private int age = 0;
    private int salary = 0;
    
    void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
    int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    void setsalary(int salary)
    {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    int getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }

Comment: package customer;


public class Customer
{
    private int age = 0;
    private int salary = 0;
    
    void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
    int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    void setsalary(int salary)
    {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    int getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }

Comment: i have set the salary check this c[0].setsalary(250);
        c[1].setsalary(350);

Comment: Instead of `c[1].getSalary=temp` write `c[1].setsalary(temp)`

Comment: It works i hope by this other step would be easy!!!